# Exception when sending thousands of mails through Mandrill API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library, mandrill, .net-4.5.2

The application makes a query through Entity Framework using table MailingLista with 300,000 records that need to be sent by Mail

Each record must be sent through the API Mandrill. Mandrill is Mail Server like Amazon SES

Mandrill's response should update the status in the MailingLista table. This update is done through a Stored Procedure in EF

I tried both PLINQ as Parallel and in both case have the same exception

Code Parallel:

```
      public void ProcessMailingParallel()
      {
         Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
         Entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
         Entities.Database.CommandTimeout = 10000;
         MandrillApi _MandrillApi = new MandrillApi(AppConfig.MailAPIKey);
         try
         {
            _Logger.Debug("Start ProcessMailing()");
            Parallel.ForEach(GetvMailingListaReadyToSend(10000).AsParallel(),
               new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 },
               _MailingLista => ProcessMail(_MailingLista));
         }
         catch (Exception _Exception)
         {
            _Logger.ErrorFormat("Excepcion: {0}", _Exception);
         }
         _Logger.Debug("End ProcessMailing()");
      }


  public void ProcessMail(vMailingListaReadyToSend vMailingLista)
  {
     EmailResult _EmailResult = null;
     try
     {
        //Create Mail
        EmailMessage _EmailMessage = new EmailMessage()
        {
           to = new EmailAddress(vMailingLista.MailTo),
           from_email = vMailingLista.MailFrom ?? AppConfig.MailFrom,
           from_name = vMailingLista.MailFromName ?? AppConfig.MailFromName,
           subject = vMailingLista.Subject,
           html = vMailingLista.Body
        };

        //Mandrill Delay is about 3-5 seconds
        _EmailResult = _MandrillApi.SendMessage(_EmailMessage);

        if (_EmailResult.IsNull())
           throw new Exception("result");

        // Update using Stored 
        UpdateMailingLista(vMailingLista.MailingListaId, DateTime.Now, 
            true, _EmailResult.Status, _EmailResult.RejectReason);
     }
     catch (Exception _Exception)
     {
        _Logger.ErrorFormat("Exception:{0}",vMailingLista.MailingListaId);
     }
  }
```

After 500 updates receive the following exception 
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

At the time the exception the connection is open

Comment: Does the exception come after exactly 10 sec?  `Entities.Database.CommandTimeout = 10000`.  If so, either increase the timeout, or get the results *before* you start sending the emails; sending the emails in the same loop as polling for the results keeps your cursor open the whole time.

Comment: I change the CommandTimeout and nothing change,
The solution I found is to create a new context

            using (MailingEntities MailingEntities context = new ())
             {
                context.SPUpdateMailingLista () ......
             }

Comment: The error is realted to ExecuteReader, where are you reading something from the DB? I don't see that code.

Answer (score -1):

The final code

Main.cs

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
             _LogHelper.Init();
             _LogHelper.AddFileLogging...
             _LogHelper.AddSMTPLogging...
             _Logger.DebugFormat("Start....
             _Timer = new Timer(AppConfig.Interval);
             _Timer.AutoReset =   true;
             _Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this._Timer_Tick);
             _Timer.Start();
    }

   private void _Timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       _Timer.Stop();
       try
       {
          using (MailingService _MailingServices = new MailingService(1000000))
          {
             _MailingServices.ProcessMailingPLinQ(); //Parallel
             //_MailingServices.ProcessMailingParallel(); //PLINQ
          }
       }
       catch (Exception _Exception)
       {
          _Logger.ErrorFormat("Exception: {0}", _Exception.GetExceptionAll());
       }
       finally
       {
          _Timer.Start();
       }
    }



Services.cs

      public void ProcessMailingPLinQ()
      {
         Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
         Entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
         MandrillApi _MandrillApi = new MandrillApi(AppConfig.MailAPIKey);
         try
         {
            _Logger.Debug("Start ProcessMailing()");
            GetvMailingListaReadyToSend(5000)
                          .AsParallel()
                          .Select(M => ProcessMail(M)).ToArray();
            //Query paginated
         }
         catch (Exception _Exception)
         {
            _Logger.ErrorFormat(....);
         }
         _Logger.Debug("End ProcessMailing()");
      }

      public void ProcessMailingParallel()
      {
         Entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
         Entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
         MandrillApi _MandrillApi = new MandrillApi(AppConfig.MailAPIKey);
         try
         {
            _Logger.Debug("Start ProcessMailing()");
            Parallel.ForEach(GetvMailingListaReadyToSend(5000).AsParallel(),
               new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 },
               _MailingLista => ProcessMail(_MailingLista));
            //Query paginated
         }
         catch (Exception _Exception)
         {
            _Logger.ErrorFormat(....);
         }
         _Logger.Debug("End ProcessMailing()");
      }

public EmailResult ProcessMail(vMailingListaReadyToSend vMailingLista)
{
   EmailResult _EmailResult = null;
   try
   {
      //Create 
      EmailMessage _EmailMessage = new EmailMessage()
      {
         .....
      };

      //Sending
      _EmailResult = _MandrillApi.SendMessage(_EmailMessage).FirstOrDefault();

      //Update
      using (MailingEntities _MailingEntitiesUpdate = new MailingEntities())
      {
         _MailingEntitiesUpdate.SPUpdateMailingLista(Id, DateTime.Now, false);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception _Exception)
   {
      _Logger.ErrorFormat(...);
   }
   return _EmailResult;
}


EntityFramework.cs
IEnumerable<vMailingListaReadyToSend> GetvMailingListaReadyToSend(int vItems)
{
         return Entities.vMailingListaReadyToSend.AsNoTracking().Take(vItems);
}
```

All improvements are welcomed!!